# How can I show that $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ for any $a$ and prime $p$ in $\mathbb Z$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Assuming $p$ is prime, how do I show that $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ for all $a$ (where $a$, $p$ $\in \mathbb Z$)?

I think I can handle the case where $p$ doesn't divide $a$, because then I can use Fermat's theorem, so I'd say that $a^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ then multiply by $a$ on both sides. But Fermat's theorem does not apply in the case that $p$ divides $a$, as $\gcd(a, p) \neq 1$.

I'm thinking maybe that since $a = kp$ for some $k$, $a^p \equiv (kp)^p \pmod p$, but I'm not sure how to show that this is congruent to $kp \pmod p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p$ divides $a$, both sides are congruent to $0$ modulo $p$.

Comment: Whelp, that was pretty stupid of me. Thanks!

Comment: haha sure. overthinking happens to me too. :p

Comment: It doesn't help that I'm trying to math at 2 in the morning...

Comment: Go to sleep if you don't have a test. If you have a test, then **GO TO SLEEP**. Sleep is important for cognitive brain functioning.

Comment: But I've got only one problem left!

Comment: haha okay. do it then sleep.